# Sequelize - Unhandled Rejection Error Not Associated

Tags: sequelize.js, sequelize-cli

I have received a bizarre association error after running a query with a table join that has a one-to-many relationship with the primary table being queried. Despite having the association set up and relationship displayed in my database as it is displayed in my model, I still receive an error. What am I missing that could be causing this? Note that the request table was created with a migration file using the cli. Could this be the key issue?

Here is the error:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: user is not associated to request!
```

Here is my query:

```
models.Request.findAll({
                include: [{
                    model: models.User
                }],
                where: {
                    $or: [{requester: req.user.userId}, {receiver: req.user.userId}]
                }
            });
```

Here is the **user** table, where the one-to-many join exists:

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var User = sequelize.define('user', {
    userId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field:'user_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    firstName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'first_name'
    },
    lastName: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        field: 'last_name'
    },
    email: {
        type: DataTypes.STRING,
        isEmail: true,
        unique: true,
        set: function(val) {
            this.setDataValue('email', val.toLowerCase());
        }
    },
    password: DataTypes.STRING,
    organizationId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'organization_id',
        allowNull: true
    },
    teamId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'team_id',
        allowNull: true
    },
}, {
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
    classMethods: {
        associate: function(db) {
            User.hasMany(db.Request, { foreignKey: 'requester'});
        },  
});
    return User;
}
```

Here is the **request** table (This table was originally migrated with the cli):

```
module.exports = function(sequelize, DataTypes) {

var path = require('path');
var moment = require('moment');
var current = new Date();
var day = ("0" + current.getDate()).slice(-2);
var month = ("0" + (current.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2);
var today = current.getFullYear() + '-' + (month) + '-' + (day); 


var Request = sequelize.define('request', {
    requestId: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'request_id',
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true
    },
    requestDate: {
        type: DataTypes.DATE,
        field: 'request_date',
        isDate: true,
        allowNull: false,
        defaultValue: today
    },
    requester: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'requester',
        references: {
            model: 'user',
            key: 'user_id'
        },
        onUpdate: 'cascade',
        onDelete: 'cascade'
    },
    receiver: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER,
        field: 'receiver'
    },
},
 {
    underscored: true,
    freezeTableName: true,
});
    return Request;
}
```

db-index (where the association is created):

```
    var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
    var path = require('path');
    var sequelize = new Sequelize(process.env.LOCAL_DATABASE || process.env.RDS_DATABASE, 
            process.env.LOCAL_USERNAME || process.env.RDS_USERNAME, 
            process.env.LOCAL_PASSWORD || process.env.RDS_PASSWORD, {
        host: process.env.RDS_HOSTNAME || 'localhost',
        port: process.env.RDS_PORT || '3306',
        dialect: 'mysql',
        timezone: 'America/New_York'
    });

    sequelize.authenticate().then(function(err) {
        if (!!err) {
            console.log('Unable to connect to the database:', err)
        } else {
            console.log('Connection has been established successfully.')
        }
    });

    var db = {}

    db.User = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/user");
    db.Request = sequelize.import(__dirname + "/request");

    db.User.associate(db);

    db.sequelize = sequelize;
    db.Sequelize = Sequelize;

    sequelize.sync();

module.exports = db;
```

Screenshot of relationship on request table:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get `User` using `Request` model, you should define association `Request->belongsTo->User`. Existed relation `User->hasMany->Request` tells us that you can get `Requests` through `User` model, not reversively

Comment: thank you for pointing that out. Is there a reason why I can't do this in the current format? It seems like I can run a query with a `LEFT JOIN` on the `user` table and get the desired result. `SELECT *
FROM request
LEFT JOIN user
ON request.requester = user.user_id;`

Comment: Sequelize is ORM, so in order to generate Sql query like this, it should know how this 2 models were associated (in your case request->user association). Sequelize also group data returned from sql query depending on defined association.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! This was very helpful!